# Equivalent of "cd %programfiles%" in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

In traditional cmd, we can use `cd %programfiles%` to switch directory which usually resolves to `C:\Program Files`.

In PowerShell, how can we go to a directory by a environment variable?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The principle is:

```
$Env:variablename
```

So you might try:

```
cd $Env:Programfiles
```

or to temporarily switch working directory to `%Programfiles%\MyApp`:

```
Push-Location -Path "$Env:Programfiles\MyApp"
#
# command execution here
#
Pop-Location
```

To list all environment variables you could do:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

or use the convenient alias:

```
ls env:
```

Comment: If I want to go to C:\Program Files\Common Files, how should I write the command? It seem very strange that I can use `cd $env:ProgramFiles"\Common Files"` without + to concatenate the two strings. Can you explain?

Comment: I found some articles explaining this: http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1153 http://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/powershell-working-with-strings/

Answer (score 14):

To see all the environment variables, do this:

```
dir env:
```

To see all the ones containing "Program", do this:

```
dir env: | ? { $_.Value -match 'Program' }
```

In PowerShell 3 it is cleaner:

```
dir env: | ? Value -match 'Program'
```

The one we want is `env:ProgramFiles`, and we can just do this:

```
cd $env:ProgramFiles
```

Comment: Really annoying how if you enter a typo in the variable name, it silently fails with no explanation.

Comment: It does offer tab-autocomplete though... kind of nice. It'd be better if `$e`-tab would autocomplete to `$env:` instead of jumping to the first environment variable, though...